# Request paypal payment with variable recipient

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Does paypal support any sort of variable transaction? where the receiver of payment is a variable?

for example, `paypal.com/pay/?to=user1@site.com&amount=10.00`

All of the merchant tools use an internal paypal user id instead of a plain email, which is fair enough as they are *merchant* tools.

I've been reading up on adaptive-payments but I don't have any need for a middle man, just a simple *`pay`*`n amount`*`to`*`x address`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing. Like this:

https://paypal.com/xclick?business=user@site.com&amount=10

... which is just a simplified GET version of the (non-encrypted) PayPal button interface POST. Pretty much all the same parameters that you can put in the POST can be used in the GET.